# Access to environment value without declare @Environment property in SwiftUI's View

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to access my custom environment value without declaring `@Environment` property in `View`. So why I need that?

Let's look at the example. I have my custom environment value:

```
enum Theme {
    case black
    case white

    func color() -> Color {
        // ... Get color functional
    }
}

struct ThemeKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: Theme = .black
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var theme: Theme {
        get { self[ThemeKey.self] }
        set { self[ThemeKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}
```

To use it I have to write `@Environment` property in my `View`, like that:

```
struct AppView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ContentView()
            .environment(\.theme, .white)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment (\.theme) private var theme

    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(theme.color())
    }
}
```

So what if I want to get access to `theme` environment value in all my Views? For example, I could write an extension to `View` which gets `theme` like that:

```
extension View {
    var theme: Theme {
        return Environment(\.theme).wrappedValue
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(theme.color())
    }
}
```

But it not works and Xcode shows me an error `Accessing Environment<Theme>'s value outside of being installed on a View. This will always read the default value and will not update.`

So my question is Do I have to add `@Environment` property in my View to access `theme` value or I can do it by other way, for example without declaring `@Environment` property?

Answer (score 1):

The error message you're encountering stems from a fundamental misunderstanding of how SwiftUI's environment system is designed to work. The `@Environment` property wrapper is specifically designed to inject environment values into your SwiftUI views. This mechanism ensures that your views automatically update when the environment value changes, adhering to SwiftUI's reactive design principles. Attempting to access an environment value directly without using `@Environment` (or another appropriate mechanism) circumvents this system, leading to the issues you've observed.

When you try to create a computed property within an extension on `View` to directly access an environment value, you're bypassing the environment's intended pattern of use. SwiftUI's environment is not just a simple dictionary that you can access values from at any point; it is a managed system that propagates values down the view hierarchy, ensuring updates are efficiently processed.

However, if your goal is to reduce boilerplate and make the theme value easily accessible within your views without explicitly declaring an `@Environment` property each time, you have a couple of alternatives:

#### 1. Using a Helper View

You can create a small helper `View` that injects the environment value into its child views. This approach allows you to abstract away the environment access:

```swift
struct WithTheme<Content: View>: View {
    @Environment(\.theme) var theme
    let content: (Theme) -> Content

    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Theme) -> Content) {
        self.content = content
    }

    var body: some View {
        content(theme)
    }
}

// Usage
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        WithTheme { theme in
            Rectangle()
                .fill(theme.color())
        }
    }
}
```

#### 2. View Modifier

Another approach is to create a custom view modifier that injects the theme into the view. This is more in line with SwiftUI's design philosophy and allows you to use environment values flexibly:

```swift
struct ThemeModifier: ViewModifier {
    @Environment(\.theme) var theme

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .fill(theme.color()) // Assuming the content can be filled with a color
    }
}

extension View {
    func withTheme() -> some View {
        modifier(ThemeModifier())
    }
}

// Usage
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .withTheme()
    }
}
```

In both approaches, you're adhering to SwiftUI's intended design by utilizing the `@Environment` property wrapper to access environment values. This ensures your views remain reactive and automatically update when the environment value changes.

Directly accessing the environment outside of these patterns is not supported by SwiftUI and, as you've discovered, leads to errors or unexpected behavior. The key is to work within the framework's guidelines to achieve the desired functionality.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. You are fully right. So I cannot use my `Theme` object in singleton, for example, due to unable our views to react when value changes, right?

Comment: I also have another way to solve this. I can use my own macro `@Theme` on View's struct, which automatically adds a code line `@Environment (\.theme) private var theme`